# Is it possible to make sub domain to route to different machine with different IP address?

Tags: networking

I just bought a domain orange.info from a webhosting company.

I want to set up my orange.info routing to two different machine with two different IPs

Is it possible to do that? One is for my cloud machine, and other one is for my home machine.

So.

```
cloud.orange.info  ---> will route to IP address A
home.orange.info ----> will route to IP address B
```

Is it possible to do that? Or do i need to buy two domains name separately.

I am a newbie on network stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You just need to create an `A` record for each subdomain and point it to the IP address. You can also point multiple records to the same address, or one record to multiple addresses (clients will pick one at random each time they try to connect).

Comment: OH i understand ! so i found that some records default are "@" or "*" what are their meaning?